# Como deletar PHPSESSID

Tags: php, session, cookies

Eu estou fazendo um carrinho com `$_SESSION` e quando a compra é finalizada, deveria limpar ou deletar o `PHPSESSID` (que é auto-criada). Porém não estou conseguindo deletar ou atualizar. Já tentei com `unset()` e `session_destroy()` e até mesmo tentando deletar como `cookie`, mas não estou conseguindo nada.

Comment: já tentou expirar antes do `unset();`

Comment: Coloque o código para vermos como você está realizando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [**session_destroy**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-destroy.php) não vai deletar o `PHPSESSID`, vai apenas remover todo o conteúdo da variável `$_SESSION`. Essa função não remove o cookie de sessão.

> Só lembrando que `session_destroy` não remove os dados de `$_SESSION` no momento que foi executada, mas sim na próxima requisição.

Caso você queira limpar todos os dados da variável `$_SESSION`, basta utilizar [**session_reset**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-reset.php). Essa função irá apagar todos os dados da variável supracitada no momento em que for executada.

Particularmente não vejo motivos de deletar o valor de `PHPSESSID` já que você pode usar as funções acima ou ainda [**unset**](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

Mas caso você realmente queira remover esse cookie, basta utilizar a função [**setcookie**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php).

```
setcookie(session_name(), null, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Já tentou isso:
Do (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-destroy.php) , 
"Nota: Não é necessário chamar session_destroy() em um código habitual. Ao invés de destruir os dados da sessão, limpe o array $_SESSION."